# Dragging parent element to include all children element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to drag a "task" element using the data attribute [data-task] below. Whenever I test the event listener it doesn't read any of the child elements nested inside the div. Is there a way / logic that I can include all the elements within? The listener only executes when I click the border-edge of the task, but ultimately I would like to drag the whole element that includes the header and task name

This problem exists when I nest the "task-header" and content itself in their own divs / html tags. If I remove those, the event listener will recognize the whole item element.

```
 <div class="task" data-task>
                <div class="task-header">
                    Task Name
                </div>
                <p>
                    Task Content
                </p>
            </div>


export default function dragAndDrop(){
   document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
       if(e.target.matches('[data-task]')){
           console.log('tasked!')
       }
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out..use e.target.matches to find the correct data attribute on target.. and then find the closest parent.. which would be data-task.. create a lone using cloneNode and then setup my offsets and such.. worked nicely!